# No visible @interface declares the selector error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a connection class in my project. I want to use this class in for a lot of works. When I tried to call this class's function getting following error  : No visible @interface declares the selector error

coreConnection.h

```
@interface coreConnection:NSArray
{
    NSData *returnData;
}
      -(NSArray*)getData;
@end
```

coreConnection.m

```
#import "coreConnection.h"

@implementation coreConnection

-(NSArray*)getData:(NSString*)link
{
    NSOperationQueue *apiCallsQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:apiCallsQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            returnData = data;
        });
    }];
    return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:nil error:nil];
}
@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "coreConnection.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[self headlineCollectionView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self headlineCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
     [self.headlineCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeadLineCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    coreConnection speed=[[coreConnection alloc] init];;
    headline = [speed getData:@"string"];
    [self.headlineCollectionView reloadData];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a hint.  Look at how you declared it in the .h file vs the .m file

Comment: To all: Here is another great example for helping asking people with down votes without comments. Great job! Some helping comments would be very helpful even if the topic is too easy for down voters. Nobody was born as an fully developed programmer. +1 for having the courage to ask a question in a lions gage.

Comment: Don't you have a problem with your getData method? you perform an asynchronous request where you update `returnData` but you return its value out of the completion handler... I also think you don't need to use dispatch_async in an asynchronous request.

Comment: rollbacked .. Make it another qustion .This is a future reference also for others ,and the answers also become improper if you change the context of question

Comment: @zbMax What can I do right, for it

Comment: @Sezgin use share button to share the info to the new question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hehe the problem is pretty simple
your method in implementation and used in code is

```
-(NSArray*)getData:(NSString*)link
```

not

```
-(NSArray*)getData;
```

which is declared in .h file 
so make the declaration as

```
-(NSArray*)getData:(NSString*)link;
```

in .h file

**EDIT**

You also missed  `*` in allocing the object

Use

```
coreConnection *speed=[[coreConnection alloc] init];;
```

Comment: Darn, I was hoping my comment would make OP be able to realize this on his own ><.  This is the correct answer though.  Maulik's also.

Comment: hehe yeah i waited more than 5 min to answer seeing your comment,but nobody get it :D lol

Comment: @LithuT.V . After discuss with **Borrrden** comments  , I came to Know but I was just supporting **Borrrden** thought..

Comment: @Sezgin did you add `-(NSArray*)getData:(NSString*)link;` in `coreConnection.h` ? and if you try it still shows error?? :O

Comment: @LithuT.V used coreConnection *speed=[[coreConnection alloc] init]; but crashed :/ all output = *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
***

Comment: That is because the data part is nil coming you need to check it and if has value must apply parser,If it is nil parser crashes

Comment: I think you should make it another question because it is not the scenario of the current question.

Comment: @Sezgin : I dont think it is proper to update the question like that.Make it an another question or serach for that issue seperately.This is for future visitors also.I think this issue you raised is over with the answer provided.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to declare your method `-(NSArray*)getData:(NSString*)link;` in `coreConnection.h` file.